# Android SDK and AVD Manager issue

Tags: android

I am trying to follow the procedure [Downloading the Google USB Driver](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html#WinUsbDriver) but see the following error in Android SDK and AVD Manager:

> Some packages were found but are not
>   compatible updates.

I am unable to [Download the Google USB Driver](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html#WinUsbDriver) without the Google Add-ons.

Specifically, I need Google Usb Driver package revision 4 for the Nexus S.

I ran Eclipse > Help > Check for updates but this did not resolve the issue.

Does the Android SDK and AVD Manager need to be updated another way? If so, how?

Is there some other way to fix this?

Does Google Usb Driver package revision 4 work in Windows XP?

[image: Android SDK and AVD Manager Error]

Comment: I have uninstalled and am re-installing the SDK. This may take a while since I am on an atom based windows XP netbook. Maybe I should get a real computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is ok. Those are shown so since they are probably not meant for your version of adt. When you update your android development tools again and check for updates you will be updated to the latest and then you may update to the tools for the latest version. You may still have that alert message since there will also be updates that are not compatible with your your version of adt.

Comment: Actually, I think you only see that message when there are no compatible updates. Think of it as Google's version of "This space intentionally left blank."

Comment: I am unable to `Downloading the Google USB Driver` without the Google Add-ons. I need the `Google Usb Driver package revision 4` for the Nexus S.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to download your latest version (zip file )of adt then install this new .zip file in eclipse.

Then you would be getting the enabled option to download Google USB driver for nexus S.

Comment: This is a new installation. I have installed the latest version of everything

Answer (score 0):

Which version of the JRE are you running? I had this problem, updated Java, fixed it immediately. I think I was running OpenJava 1.5, upgraded to 1.6 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the sdk manager in admin mode, has seemed to help me in the past with strange errors

Answer (score 0):

After completely uninstalling and re-installing the SDK I was able to see and install the Google USB driver but still have been unable to connect the debugger. Perhaps Android development on an Atom based XP Net-Book is a bad idea. I've not been able to get the emulator working so I thought it might be better debugging directly on the target. The emulator just locks up this PC. I've waited up to 40 minutes before giving up. I've had no trouble with Android development on my work PC (emulator or target) but I have some personal projects I'd rather not do on company equipment. Oh well, I probably just need a real PC if I want to work at home.

Answer (score 0):

Issue - I had a working Android Studio and USB driver would allow me to connect to my Huawei Honor 6X mobile device. One day the Android Studio stopped detecting the mobile device and reinstalling Huawei drivers, uninstalling and reinstalling drivers did not work. I tried changing cables and it did not work either. My Windows 8 would not detect the phone when I connected it with USB and Studio did not detect the device either.

Various solutions posted at the forums did not work for me. Finally this is what I did to solve the issue. My LG mobile also works with the Android Studio and I believe this solution will work for all mobile devices and not just Huawei device 
Solution - 
1) Open Tools> Android > SDK Manager > SDK Tools tab
2) Select Show package details check box
3) Is Google USB Driver selected? Select it if it is not selected, apply & Ok.
3) If Google USB Driver is selected, unselect it and SDK manager will remove the USB drivers.
4) Close Android Studio and follow the above theps and select the Google USB Driver and let studio update the driver
5)Close Android Studio Again
6) Go to Device Manager and you should see 'Android Composite ADB Interface' if the driver is successfully installed

[image]

7) That is it, now open Android Studio & when you run the application you should see your mobile device under Connected Devices

[image]

Comment: You can follow this tutorial to install ADB driver                               
 Youtube-
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UkI9v878btI